# Проверить сущестование файла и отправить данные в коллекцию

Tags: c#, коллекции

Нужно проверить существование файла по путям из List dino, если имеются несуществующие файлы, то удалить эти пути и снова передать эти новые данные в лист dino либо в новый лист, чтобы можно было далее в циклах использовать эти пути.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] basePaths =
    {
    "folders\\text.txt",
    "folders\\text.txt",
    "folders\\text.txt"
    };

    List<string> dino = new List<string>(basePaths);
```

Пробую это все делать через цикл, но в цикле нельзя изменять данные коллекции

```
foreach (string dino2 in dino)
{
    if (!(File.Exists(dino2)))
        dino.Remove(dino2);
}
```

Просмотрел много примеров в документации и в интернете, ничего не нашел схожего, возможно просто не наткнулся на нужный вариант
UPD: пробовал цикл for, программа останавливается

```
List<string> dino = new List<string>(basePaths);

for (int i = dino.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (!(File.Exists(dino[i])))
    {
        dino.Remove(dino[i]);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(dino[i]);
}
```

Comment: @Андрей NOP, отладка на выводе из консоли останавливалась, уже исправил моя ошибка была

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь есть несколько решений:

Классический способ, в данном случае — воспользоваться циклом `for`, но, при этом, для того, чтобы удаление элементов не влияло на их перебор, следует идти с конца списка:

```
for (int i = dino.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    if (!File.Exists(dino[i]))
        dino.RemoveAt(i);
```

Следующий способ — воспользоваться встроенными в класс List средствами для массового удаления элементов, удовлетворяющих некоторому условию:

```
dino.RemoveAll(e => !File.Exists(e));
```

Ну и, наконец, более современный способ, с оттенками функционального программирования, но, в данном случае, скорее всего, не самый эффективный — воспользоваться Linq. Имейте ввиду, Linq не изменяет коллекции (последовательности), он создает новые, поэтому вам придется явно перезаписать ссылку на коллекцию:

```
dino = dino.Where(e => File.Exists(e)).ToList();
```

Comment: как раз редактировал вопрос с добавлением цикла for с перебором с конца) Проверил по Вашему примеру, теперь коллекция изменилась)

Comment: спасибо за помощь!